# How to correct my code of binary search in an array

Tags: java

I was implementing a code for binary search in an array in java 
here is my code:

```
public class Exam {

    public static boolean find(int[]a, int k){

        int mid = a.length/2;
        if (a[mid]==k) {
            return true;
        }
        else if (a[mid] < k) {
            for (int i=0; i<a[mid]; i++) {
                if (a[i]==k) {
                    return true;
                } 
        }

        } else {
            for (int ii=mid; ii<a[a.length]; ii++) {
                if (a[ii]==k) {
                    return true;
                }
        }
    }
        return false;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] a = { 2, 3, 4, 9, 11, 15 };

        System.out.println(find(a,3));

    }

}
```

When I run it I get error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
    at shapes.Exam.find(Exam.java:20)
    at shapes.Exam.main(Exam.java:34)
```

But when I run this line instead:

```
System.out.println(find(a,15));
```

I get correct output as following:

```
true
```

What is the wrong with my code?

Comment: You're not doing binary search here; you're just searching half of the array. That's still has linear complexity.

Comment: Maybe we need some sort of codehomeworkhelp exchange. Would make these easier to deal with.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `i<a[mid]` and `ii<a[a.length]` as your loop guard conditions.

Comment: `for (int i=0; i<a[mid]` is not correct. You want i to go from 0 to mid, not a[mid]. Also, even when all the bugs are fixed, this is not binary search. It's just a linear search on a half of an array. A binary search would repeat the split in half until the value is found (or at least until the numberof remaining elements is small enough for a linear search.

Answer (score -1):

Here:

```
 for (int ii=mid; ii<a[a.length]; ii++) {
```

for last element of an array it should be `a[a.length-1]`

Comment: does not work. I get same error. thanks

Comment: `mid` is the index of the middle element of the array. What is `a[a.length]` or `a[a.length - 1]`?

Comment: @AndyTurner logicly IDK, semanticly reason for given exception.

Comment: You'd still get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` with that change - for a different reason, but the same exception.